# Проблема с получением кадров с помощью OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

Установила OpenCV на Raspberry Pi 3, создала (на самом деле взяла из [туториала](http://robotclass.ru/tutorials/opencv-video-rgb-hsv-gray/)) файл для получения кадров по алгоритму: [Получение кадра с камеры]-->[Отображение кадра в окне]

Сам код:

```
import cv2
import video

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # создаем окно с именем result
    cv2.namedWindow( "result" )

    # создаем объект cap для захвата кадров с камеры
    cap = video.create_capture(0)

    while True:
        # захватываем текущий кадр и кладем его в переменную img 
        flag, img = cap.read()
        try:
            # отображаем кадр в окне с именем result
            cv2.imshow('result', img)
        except:
            cap.release()
            raise

        ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if ch == 27:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

И ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "eye.py", line 6, in 
>   cv2.namedWindow( "result" ) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0-pre)
>   /home/pi/Downloads/opencv-
>   master/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:615: error: (-2:Unspecified
>   error) The  function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with
>   Windows, GTK+ 2.x or  Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian,
>   install libgtk2.0-dev and  pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure
>   script in function 'cvNamedWindow'

Из того, что нам пишут в ошибке можно понять, что просят установить *libgtk2.0-dev* и *pkg-config*, перезапустить cmake или настроить скрипт функции.При установке *libgtk2.0-dev* вылезают ошибки и фэйлы (скорее всего из-за того, что он уже установлен), а pkg-config пишет, что ничего нового не внесено.

Не пойму, как перезапустить Cmake и как "настроить скрипт функции". Если есть мысли, как это должно работать и как исправить, буду очень благодарна

Comment: Попробуйте скачать предыдущую версию OpenCV: `wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.zip` так как пример на который вы ссылаетесь может не работать для 4.0.0

Comment: вы этот пример удаленно через консоль запускаете или через графическую оболочку прямо с малинки?

Comment: @kidig , нет, этот пример создан и запускается непосредстенно в файле.py.
По вашему комментарию я могу сделать вывод, что нужно в консоли запускать, в граф. оболочке, так ведь?

Comment: @mr NAE , спасибо за совет, обязательно воспользуюсь